# delaying a statement in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two lines of javascript here, when the toggle function executes i want to delay before the find function happens.

```
$activeToggle.toggle("fast"); // i want this to run and then after 1250 millisec
$activeToggle.find(".anime").each(function (i,e){ // this code runs

        alert(e.id);

    });
```

I want to delay the second line of code to execute, because for some reason the alert is happening before the toggle action takes place, so their must a be way to delay the second line. thanks

Comment: How about you use the toggle's animation callback? That way you can make the popup appear at the precise moment it is done animating...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of the callback function. This ensures the toggle has finished executing before running the loop function you have.

```
$activeToggle.toggle("fast", function(){
   $(this).find(".anime").each(function (i,e){ // this code runs

        alert(e.id);

    });
})
```

This way you don't need to delay. Your code will be ran immediately after the `toggle()` function.

Comment: OP stated he wants a delay of 1250 ms before the find function.

Comment: @j08691 I believe this is only because OP wants to make sure `toggle()` has finished executing. My code ensures it has.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method:

```
   $activeToggle.delay(1250).toggle("fast");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout( function () { $activeToggle.toggle("fast"); }, 1250);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of jQuerys delay function :)

```
$activeToggle.delay(1250).toggle("fast", function(){
   $(this).find(".anime").each(function (i,e){ // this code runs

        alert(e.id);

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Aswell as using a call back you can foce your code to wait before execution using `.stop()`

```
$activeToggle.toggle("fast"); // i want this to run and then after 1250 millisec
$activeToggle.find(".anime").stop(true,true).each(function (i,e){ // this code runs
        alert(e.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to trigger a function after the animation is complete, then you can pass [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) a callback function that only runs after the animation is complete.

```
$activeToggle.toggle("fast", function() {
    $activeToggle.find(".anime").each(

    function(i, e) {
        alert(e.id);
    });
});
```